# How can I just read data using the new Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, cron, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am in a situation where I need to read the Firebase Realtime Database with a "cron" job.

I analysed and played with [this](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) repository, but I can't seem to understand how I can simply retrieve the list of ALL of the users or all of the data in the Realtime Database. The only function of the `functions.database.ref` is `onWrite`, which doesn't help me.

I know that the Cloud Functions are event-oriented and they were written to respond to some triggers etc, but as far as I [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron), this is not impossible and we can apparently access the data.
In their 'delete accounts' example, they used this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/downloadAccount?fields=users/localId,users/lastLoginAt,nextPageToken&access_token=
```

And it seems quite undocumented and not at all explained. Why do we have to use the identity toolkit? How could I simply READ data? What I've tried to do until the moment:

- Use `functions.database.ref('users').once('value', function(snapshot){})`and it didn't work
- Use their cron job example code (identity toolkit), but I get a highly strange response in the logs from Firebase: `Missing required header: Metadata-Flavor` and the rest of the tracking below:

[image: 3]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `functions.database.ref()` for reading data.  That's only for specifying the path where you want to changes to the database to trigger your function.  To write a cron-like function, you're not going to write a database trigger.  You probably want an HTTP trigger instead, as shown in the [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron).  You trigger than HTTP function with a third party scheduler as described in the readme.

To read data from the database in that function, you should use the admin SDK, as shown in that code sample.  It's initialized here, and appears in lots of other code samples as well:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Then you can get a reference to the database:

```
const ref = admin.database().ref(`/path/to/data`);
```

ref here is a Reference object.  You can [read data with that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data).  Be sure to look at the other code samples too - many of them read a database with the admin SDK like this.